# How do I reference table B rows twice from table A?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, data-modeling

I'm new to data modeling, so please excuse the newbie questions:

How do I make a reference twice in 2 columns, to the same table? If I just made the reference once I would link them together by calling the column LocationID. E.g. I have a table called Locations, and a table called Tours:

Locations:
ID (pk),
Country,
State,
Street address,
etc

Tours:
ID (pk),
Start location (how do i make this reference?),
End location (and this one?),
locations visited,
description,
cost,
date,
etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE locations
(
  id INT NOT NULL,
  country VARCHAR(64),
  state  VARCHAR(64),
  street_address  VARCHAR(64),
  PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE tours
(
  id INT NOT NULL,
  start_location INT NOT NULL,
  end_location INT NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(255),
  cost DECIMAL(19,2),
  date DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (start_location) REFERENCES locations (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (end_location) REFERENCES locations (id)
);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b774a/3)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Give the table name aliases and then reference them with their new names as if they were separate tables, such as:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TOURS
JOIN
  LOCATIONS START_LOCATION ON
  START_LOCATION.LOCATION_ID = TOURS.START_LOCATION
JOIN
  LOCATIONS END_LOCATION ON
  END_LOCATION.LOCATION_ID = TOURS.END_LOCATION
```